# Generating XML and writing to file system from DB2

Tags: cobol, database-trigger, cics, db2-zos

I need suggestion/best approach to address the below problem:

On insertion of a new record into a DB2 table, a file needs to be generated and stored remotely on real time

Env. DB2/zOS

Comment: Is IBM-MQ available?  If so, I'd use that.  And did at one time.

Comment: I agree with @cschneid that seems like the best option if it is available

Comment: Thanks @cschneid. I will give it a try